# Can you order labels around in NEO4J?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, label

Even if I

```
'set node:A, B, C'
```

sometimes the order doesn't get translated but what's funny is once a label becomes the head, it always stays the head. So.. if I

```
'remove node:A'
```

and re add

```
'set node:A'
```

'A' still becomes the head.

I need the order to translate in order for me to use

```
'head(labels(node))'
```

so I can use specific label.

Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Labels are ordered by internal id's which stay the same.

Two things you can do:

```
HEAD(FILTER(l in labels(node) WHERE l = "FOO")) -> FOO or NULL
ANY(l in labels(node) WHERE l = "FOO") -> predicate true or false
```

In 2.1

```
UNWIND labels(n) as l
ORDER BY l
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: That's great to know! Sorry for the late reply, been caught up with other things. I'll give this a whirl soon and let you know